# FFMpeg4Android picture to video command doesn't work

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I work with FFMpeg4Android to edit and create videos. I run a command but it doesn't work, the command goes and proceeds but in logcat I can see that the "transcoding failed" and the out1.mp4 doesn't work.
I took my command from : [ffmpeg officel site](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images).

My code:

```
String str2="ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/videokit/pic1.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/videokit/out1.mp4";
    try {
        setCommand(str2);
        runTranscoing();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("FFMpeg","couldn't execute command");
    }
```

LogCat (doesn't fit): `[full LogCat](http://www32.zippyshare.com/v/90106520/file.html)

Thanks in advance